# How to keep track of instances of another class in a class?

Tags: c#

I have created a Sales class that keeps track of the name of the product, when it was sold and the price. I have a class called Client. How can I keep track of instances of the class Client in sales?

```
 class Sales
  {
    string productname;
    double price;
    private DateTime _salesDate;

    public Sales(string productname, double price)
    {
        this.productname = productname;
        this.price = price;
        _salesDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: why not simply add a Client property to your sales class?

Comment: I want to keep track of whom I sold the item to.

Comment: You could create a`List<Client>` object  as part of the Sales state.

Comment: I'd expect to see following *data tables*: Product[Id, Name, ...], Client[Id, Name, ... ] and Sales[Id, ProductId, ClientId, ...]. This means `Sales` class have to contain `ClientId` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like the easiest way to do what you want is to add a property to the Sales class of type Client:

```
class Sales
{
    string productname;
    double price;
    private DateTime _salesDate;

    public Sales(string productname, double price, Client soldTo)
    {
        this.productname = productname;
        this.price = price;
        this.SoldTo = soldTo;
        _salesDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Client SoldTo {get; private set;} // Added public to the property
}
```

If a single `Sale` can be to multiple clients, use a `List<Client>` instead of a single `Client` both in the constructor and as the property type.

Comment: I get Error 1 The accessibility modifier of the 'objekto1_1.Sales.soldTo.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'objekto1_1.Sales.soldTo'  How do I fix that?

Comment: Opps, sorry, I've missed the public access modifier of the property. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `List<Client> _soldToClients` properties to your Sales Class

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
class Sales
{
    string productname;
    double price;
    private DateTime _salesDate;
    private List<Client> _SoldTheItemTo;

    public Sales(string productname, double price)
    {
        this.productname = productname;
        this.price = price;
        _salesDate = DateTime.Now;

        Client C = new Client();
        C.Name = "XYZ";
        _SoldTheItemTo.Add(C);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the client information in this way? you need to pass it to the constructor somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Create class for product and it's related properties.

```
public class Product
{
     double price;
     string productname;

     public Product(string productname, double price)
     {
        this.productname = productname;
        this.price = price;
     }
}
```

And Your Sale Class,

```
public class Sale
{
     List<Product> Products;
     Client _SoldTheItemTo;

     public Sale(List<Product> products, Client client)
     {
        _SoldTheItemTo = client;
        Products = products;
     }
}
```

Try to keep separate each objects, as you know sales have multiple products and you will create separate invoice for each customer so no need to keep clients list, keep list of products and manage it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop this in the proper mannner with loose coupling then you should implement this in the "**Observer Design Pattern**". The Observer defines a one-to-many relationship so that when one object changes state, the others are notified and updated automatically.
Go through below links, study properly and then implement your problem:

[Observer Design Pattern Reference 1](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern)

[Observer Design Pattern Reference 2](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)